# Strip MPLS header using DPDK

Tags: c, packet, dpdk, mpls

I am trying to strip MPLS header using DPDK, I have use the flow_filtering sample application as starting and tried to add another item in the pattern:
**Ethernet
MPLS
IPv4
END**
and I added the following action:
**RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_OF_POP_MPLS
RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_END**
But while executing the code following error is thrown:
**Flow can't be created 16 message: Not supported action.**

Following is the snippet of the code:

```
    action[0].type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_OF_POP_MPLS;
    action[1].type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_END;

    
    pattern[0].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_ETH;

    pattern[1].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_MPLS;
    
    memset(&ip_spec, 0, sizeof(struct rte_flow_item_ipv4));
    memset(&ip_mask, 0, sizeof(struct rte_flow_item_ipv4));
    ip_spec.hdr.dst_addr = htonl(dest_ip);
    ip_mask.hdr.dst_addr = dest_mask;
    ip_spec.hdr.src_addr = htonl(src_ip);
    ip_mask.hdr.src_addr = src_mask;
    pattern[2].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_IPV4;
    pattern[2].spec = &ip_spec;
    pattern[2].mask = &ip_mask;

    pattern[3].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_END;

    res = rte_flow_validate(port_id, &attr, pattern, action, error);
```

By removing the **pattern[1].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_MPLS;** and **action[0].type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_OF_POP_MPLS;**. The code works fine.

I tried to change the order of MPLS in pattern even though MPLS header reside between L2 and L3 layer but no use.

Version:

Linux: CentOS 7

DPDK: 19.08.2

NIC: X520

Firmware version: 18.5.17

Comment: Please update the dpdk version, Nic used, firmware of NIC, linux version

Comment: @VipinVarghese edited the post and added current versions. Do I need to update these?

Comment: posted the reason for error message. If you find it useful please accept and upvote, this will close the question and help others to find the right answer to similar question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Intel NIC `X520` the error message ***Flow can't be created 16 messages: Not supported action*** is the right and expected behaviour. Hence there is no issue in DPDK IXGBE PMD driver.

Explanation:

1. RTE_FLOW is NIC based on Hardware Offload to filter and modify packets in both ingress and egress directions, more details [here](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/rte_flow.html).
2. There are multiple filter tags (like vlan, IP, TCP, UDP, MPLS) along with various action items (push pop vlan, push pop mpsl, dec inc mpls ttl, ...etc). But not all filter and actions are supported by all NIC (as these are optional).
3. Refer ***Table 1.3 rte_flow actions availability in networking drivers*** (link [here](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/overview.html)) which maps each NIC PMD with the action. IXGBE is not shown to support MPLS actions.
4. Checking the PMD code [here](https://git.dpdk.org/dpdk/tree/drivers/net/ixgbe/ixgbe_flow.c), even shows supported filter fields.

```
    const struct rte_flow_item_ipv4 *ipv4_spec;
    const struct rte_flow_item_ipv4 *ipv4_mask;
    const struct rte_flow_item_tcp *tcp_spec;
    const struct rte_flow_item_tcp *tcp_mask;
    const struct rte_flow_item_udp *udp_spec;
    const struct rte_flow_item_udp *udp_mask;
    const struct rte_flow_item_sctp *sctp_spec;
    const struct rte_flow_item_sctp *sctp_mask;
    const struct rte_flow_item_eth *eth_spec;
    const struct rte_flow_item_eth *eth_mask;
    const struct rte_flow_item_vlan *vlan_spec;
    const struct rte_flow_item_vlan *vlan_mask;
```

Hence the code and IXGBE PMD behaviour are consistent and there is no error. It is the expectation from `X550` to support an unsupported feature that is incorrect.

[EDIT-1] `according to the sheet, none of the drivers support the "of_pop_mpls" action which implies that we can't strip off the MPLS header using RTE_FLOWS`

That is the correct understanding, so far the current available foundational NIC shows none support MPLS pop/push. But I am familiar with Intel NIC FM10K which allowed MPLS POP/PUSH, but I do not see that NIC is supported under DPDK. SO you have 2 options,

- use smart nic to do it HW
- use DPDK RX-callback to invoke the function to pop the MPLS tag and TX callback to push MPLS tag

Note: PTYPE is supported in most NIC, and parsing of MPLS and saving tin rte_mbuf will be available too. This will also help while using SW approach.

Comment: Your answer is really useful, But I have another question from the reference link in point 3, none of the drivers support the "of_pop_mpls" action, I was thinking of using X710 which uses the i40e driver, it supports the rte_flow type for Mpls but doesn't support "of_pop_mpls" action. In that case, what should I do?

Comment: @TanzeelAhmed first as suggested accept and upvote to close the current question.

Comment: I marked it as a correct answer based on the information provided in the comment but according to the sheet, none of the drivers support the "of_pop_mpls" action which implies that we can't strip off the MPLS header using RTE_FLOWS.

Comment: updated in the answer to helping you understand a bit better and alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir!
I don't have enough scores to upvote your comment but whenever I have. I'll surely upvote this